# select rows has numeric length more than x

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these values in a database under field name : `username` and table name : `users`

```
 ... |  username   | ...
--------------------------
     |    a651378   |

     |     b3789    |

     |  c3125621903 |

     |    d32168    |

     |    e789532   |

     | f41589964312 |
```

For example how to select username where it has a number **length greater than 6 digits**

As the above values the query should return

```
... |  username    | ...
--------------------------
    | c3125621903  |

    | f41589964312 |
```

Comment: should return 0 rows, i want to get rows contains numbers has a length more than 6 digits

Comment: ok edited, hope its clear now

Comment: All strings are comprised of a number preceded by a single character. I despair for humanity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you do not know how long the character portions are, you can use regular expressions:

```
select u.*
from users u
where u.username regexp '^.*[0-9]{7}.*$';
```

Actually, this can be simplified to:

```
select u.*
from users u
where u.username regexp '[0-9]{7}';
```

When using regular expressions, I just like to be careful.  `LIKE` patterns match the whole string (from the beginning to the end).  `REGEXP` patterns match within a string.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(username) > 7
```

[CHAR_LENGTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html) function

Comment: this will calculate the entire username length,  i want to get rows contains numbers has a length more than 6 digits

Comment: It seems that `username` field contain a number preceded by a character (a-z). If records would be like this (as i see), this query always returns the result which you desire.